# Issue with using Android swipe to dismiss ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-adapter

I am using the swipe-to-dismiss library but the app crashes after after the list item is swiped away. 
I am using the following code :

```
todolist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.todo_items);
        SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener touchListener =
                new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener(
                        todolist,
                        new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.DismissCallbacks() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean canDismiss(int position) {
                                return true;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onDismiss(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                                for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                                    mAdapter.remove(mAdapter.getItem(position));
                                }
                                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });
        todolist.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
        todolist.setOnScrollListener(touchListener.makeScrollListener());
```

The app gives a UnsupportedoperationException on this line :

```
com.example.todolist.ToDoListActivity$1.onDismiss(ToDoListActivity.java:81)
```

How do I fix this ?
I am referring to this code sample :

https://github.com/romannurik/Android-SwipeToDismiss/blob/master/src/com/example/android/swipedismiss/MainActivity.java

Thanks !

Comment: are you extending with ListActivity?

Comment: No. But I have modified my code accordingly.

Comment: I think the api relies on listactivity, Once it dismisses a row of the listview it reloads and finds inheritance of listactivity.

Comment: I tried that. Still not working